# Intercept url in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to understand how uel-interception works in spring security. Let assume that we write the following rule in our security config:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/super/**" access="ROLE_WE_DONT_HAVE"/>
```

My question is is Spring Security going to create the object of [AbstractSecurityInterceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java) or what? I need to understand that because if my assumption about creation an object for each rule right I'm going to create the instances dynamically by myself in order to control authentication rule dynamically in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically spring security will create one instance of FilterSecurityInterceptor
this filter will read the url pattern and will try to protected the mapped url
more information here [spring security core](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html)